# Exact Search in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, full-text-search

I'm performing a search on Apache Solr but it returns me several items that are out of the search.

For example, I have three items, Samsung Tablet 7 "Tablet Samsung 10.1" and Samsung TV, searching only for Samsung TV it returns with the Samsung Tablet.

How would be the query to find Samsung Tablet 10.1 and only return this item and not return the other tablets and not the TV?

```
http://url-site.com/collection1/select?q=*tv%20samsung*&start=0&rows=16&sort=name+asc&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=cat_id&facet.field=atributos&facet.field=manu_id&fq=price:[0.01+TO+*]
```

Comment: Have you tried [edismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) with mm=100%?

Comment: @leoh, tks, this works.

Comment: that's great to know. I have added the comment as answer in case others find the Q&A helps

Comment: I just add this params in the URL: `&defType=edismax&mm=100%25&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [**eDisMax**](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax) query with mm=100%